# Return a multiple lined string with a specific number of characters

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a very long string that I would like to output in the following format:

I need to output a maximum number of characters say 40 per line while I maintain a maximum of say 5 lines and discard the rest.  This should be the return string of the webservice (SOAP).

Here is a snippet of what am trying to implement.

```
String output = "A veeery long string with more than 200 characters";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(output);
int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 40)) != -1)
{
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());

result = sb.toString();
...

return result;
```

Now the `System.out.println(sb.toString());` works just fine, but when I user the webservice tester it returns 1 line on the browser which is not what I wanted to achieve

Comment: It worked fine for me, what else are you doing between assigning the buffer to result and returning it?

Comment: just catching some exceptions. nothing that can affect the output at all

Comment: Well, for browser output - which is interpreted as HTML - you need `<br>` instead of simple newlines. The question is: What does it look like when being viewed without a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source of the page in your browser, are the lines split?  If so, you will need to replace the newlines with `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Guava library for these kinds of operations. Have a look at [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Also, try to search on the website beforehand, since there's ton of questions like these :)

Comment: It's splitting when it ouputs on the console, but I want the same result output on the broweser which it's not doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this....

```
result = result + sb.toString();
```

when you do this `result = sb.toString();` then you are making result to point to a new String object, and it looses the reference to the previous String object.

using `result = result + sb.toString();` you **STILL ARE POINTING TO A NEW STRING OBJECT**, but this time the new String object has the previous and current String.

Comment: am getting this as an output using the tester even after I implement the above `Method returned`
`java.lang.String : "the same very long string in one line on the browser"`